# Difference between SingleTask and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to understand the difference between SingleTask and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. It seems that both are working in the same manner.
Ex- I created Activity A -> B -> c -> D -> E where launch mode of C is SingleTask.
Now if I open C from E then on back press I get A -> B -> c
The same thing happens when I launch C from E with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
Not sure what is the difference between these two.

Answer (score 5):

If you set `launchMode="singleTask"` but do not also set `taskAffinity` on the `<activity>` then the launch mode is ignored. This is the reason that you see no difference in the behaviour.

If you set `launchMode="singleTask"` and `taskAffinity=""` on `C` and then have this task stack: A->B and then B launches C, you will end up with 2 separate tasks: One task has A->B and the other task contains C. If you were then to press the HOME button, you would see 2 tasks of your app in the list of recent tasks.

Comment: i think it's not "ignored" totally but rather behaves like `singleTop` with `CLEAR_TOP` flag set on the intent. otherwise it would create another instance of activity C on top of the stack, right?

Comment: @stdout that is correct, `singleTask` routes an activity that exists in any existent task and destroys all the activities above it, which is what `CLEAR_TOP` and `singleTop` would achieve together.